# Children's book about a girl in a wheelchair who time travels into the past, where she's from

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

The main character is a girl in a wheelchair who can't remember her past or walk. Her name is Anna or Hanna, I think. She is adopted by new parents and visits an old boarding house and remembers her past and the ability to walk. She goes back in time to see her parents. She also goes back to the 19th century and rescues a boy from slavery and brings him forward to the current day.

I think it was published in the mid 1990s.

Comment: Wheelchair and time travel in https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9557683-whirl-of-the-wheel, but not the other details.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I think it was roughly published in the mid 90s. The girl goes back to the 19th century and rescues her friend (a boy) from slavery.

Answer (score 12):

*Ghost Hotel* by Larry Weinberg

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1888731.Ghost_Hotel):

> Anna, an adopted child, has always wondered who her real parents are.
> When Anna and her family check into a strange old hotel, Anna meets
> the ghostly Colonel and Mrs. Terwilliger. Her resemblance to the
> couple's missing daughter is eerie - especially since the young girl
> disappeared over one hundred and forty years ago!
>
> Unable to resist the lure of the past, Anna is drawn back in time to
> the danger-filled days of the Underground Railroad, which helped
> runaway slaves to freedom. Here Anna discovers the mystery of her
> childhood - a mystery that must be solved if Anna is ever to find her
> way home again.

Reviews mention her having amnesia and bringing a boy to the present.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much! 